# Linux kernel 2.6 - layer 7 support?

Tags: linux-kernel, qos

From what I found on the Internet, Layer7 classifier support is not merged into the current kernel (as of **2.6.39-rc6**) and can be achieved with a patch. Is it known when (if ever) the support will be build into the kernel?